# Replace div element with html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I have a problem replacing `div` element with `ajax`. The idea is start/stop button. There's a list of `card` elements on the page, each with its own button. Both buttons are stored in separate `html` files.

work_order_start.html:

```
<div type="button" class="repairToggle" order_id="{{ order.id }}" func="start">
  <svg>...</svg>
</div>
```

work_order_pause.html:

```
<div type="button" class="repairToggle" order_id="{{ order.id }}" func="stop">
  <svg>...</svg>
</div>
```

Initially only one is rendered on the page based of `if` condition:

```
{% if order.status == 'DN' %}
  {% include 'mtn/work_order_pause.html' %}
{% else %}
  {% include 'mtn/work_order_start.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

Here's my script:

```
    var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".repairToggle");
    for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
      btns[i].addEventListener("click", manageOrderStatus);
    }
    function manageOrderStatus() {
      var order_id = this.getAttribute("order_id");
      var func = this.getAttribute("func");
      if(func == 'start'){
        var endpoint = "{% url 'ajax_start_order' %}";
      } else {
        var endpoint = "{% url 'ajax_stop_order' %}";
      }
      $.ajax({
        url: endpoint,
        type: "GET",
        data: {
          'order_id': order_id,
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $(this).html(data);
        }
      });
    }
```

and my views:

```
def start_repair(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'mtn/work_order_pause.html')

def end_repair(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'mtn/work_order_start.html')
```

The view executes correctly, but `$(this).html(data);` doesn't replace one `div` with another. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: $(this) refers to ajax context. You need to store $(this) in one variable outside of ajax call. Probably this will solve your problem. Without full code, not able to figure out. Check if this works

Comment: It seems you are on the right track. I assigned var btn = this; outside the ajax and it worked.

Comment: Please mark as answered, so that for others it will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(this) refers to ajax context. You need to store $(this) in one variable outside of ajax call. Probably this will solve your problem. Without full code, not able to figure out. Check if this works

Comment: I found another issue: the script doesn't refresh ```var```s after ```ajax```. The ```func``` value stays the same. How do i fix that?